# CustomerAddress cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value is already being tracked

Tags: mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to code a POST api endpoint that saves customer data.  It's a JSON object with name and email, and an array of address objects.

```
customers.MapPost("/", async (Customer customer, HttpContext context, AppDBContext dbContext) =>
{
  Guid userId = (Guid)context.Items["UserId"];
  var user = await dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId.ToString());

  Customer c = new Customer();
  c.Email = customer.Email;
  c.Name = customer.Name;
    
  user.Customers.Add(c);
  dbContext.Customers.Add(c);
  await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    
  foreach (var address in customer.CustomerAddresses)
  {
    CustomerAddress ca = new CustomerAddress();

    // This works now
    ca.CustomerId = c.Id;
    ca.AddressLine1 = address.AddressLine1;
    ca.AddressLine2 = address.AddressLine2;
    ca.AddressLine3 = address.AddressLine3;
    ca.Suburb = address.Suburb;
    ca.State = address.State;
    ca.Postcode = address.Postcode;
    ca.CountryCode = address.CountryCode;

    dbContext.CustomerAddresses.Add(ca);
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
  }

  return Results.Created($"/api/v1/customers/{c.Id}", c);
}
```

If I try this, I keep getting an error about a CustomerAddress that has the same Id.  In MySQL, I have the primary key like this:

id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT(UUID())

I have tried selecting UUID() in a loop in MySQL shell, and it seems capable of creating a new one each time.  I am not sure why I can't seem to create a new CustomerAddress and save it with the new ID above.

Looks like I might need a separate endpoint to save the addresses, with the customer created first, so the ID can be attached to each address.  Seems like a lot of work; not sure why I can't just do it all at once.

Any ideas?

I have tried separating data where the JSON contains arrays of objects and creating new endpoints, but it seems less optimal than just doing it all at once.  I wonder why I can't just create new objects for each one in an array and save it to the database.

I have looked at a lot of previous posts having the same problem, but there are a lot of different answers and none of them make much sense. It's all down to EF.core change tracking, but I can't make heads or tails of it.  After saving changes for each customer address above, shouldn't the UUID be generated in the database, and ef.core knows that it's a new customer address each time?  Something like that? :-/

Answer (score 0):

EF Core should automatically reassing foreign keys, just work with references.
Removed not needed code, added missing code.

```cs
Guid userId = (Guid)context.Items["UserId"];
var user = await dbContext.Users
    .Include(u => u.Customers)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId.ToString());

if (user == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}

Customer c = new Customer();
c.Email = customer.Email;
c.Name = customer.Name;

// user and it's customers is already tracked
user.Customers.Add(c);

foreach (var address in customer.CustomerAddresses)
{
    CustomerAddress ca = new CustomerAddress();

    ca.AddressLine1 = address.AddressLine1;
    ca.AddressLine2 = address.AddressLine2;
    ca.AddressLine3 = address.AddressLine3;
    ca.Suburb = address.Suburb;
    ca.State = address.State;
    ca.Postcode = address.Postcode;
    ca.CountryCode = address.CountryCode;

    // jus add reference to customer
    customer.Addresses.Add(ca);
}

// one big SaveChanges
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  It seems to make a lot of sense, but I am still having the same error: System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Customer' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: a71445b9-626f-11ee-a488-0a0027000014}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Comment: I think if I change everything to generate the primary key in the code and explicitly generate a UUID every time, maybe I can avoid this problem?  Seems like it might be better to try and turn off this change tracking altogether though if it needs a lot of workarounds and hacks to work.

Comment: Who assigned `CustomerId`? I do not see this in code. It should be done by EF Core.

Comment: I thought it would assign Customer ID as well. It had to use the Include() as you wrote above to add the customerId I think.  Maybe it's because I generated the models and dbContext from the database schema rather than writing the models and generating a migration then running it?  Somehow that is confusing .net and it's not picking up on how the models are related?  I don't know.

Comment: Show exception call stack.